# Automated export of SQL Server data

Tags: sql-server, automation, export

I want to export large amounts of data, out of a SQL Server 2008 Enterprise, to a flat file. Then delete that data.  Naturally the delete must only happen if the export succeeds, so this must be synchronous.

Ideally this would be parametrized for date ranges. The filename also needs to change to reflect the exported data (i.e. exported_data_20110401_20110501.tsv, or similar)

I want this to be automated so that it can happen periodically.

What's the best workflow/tools to make this happen these days? The SSIS functionality seems a bit deprecated in SQL Server 2008?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) is definitely not deprecated in SQL Server 2008.

You could use a dataflow task in SSIS to export the data to a flat file (which has the filename defined with an variable), and then have an executable task to DELETE, TRUNCATE or SWITCH OUT (if you're using partitions) the exported data.

You could also have a batch (.bat) file with analogous functions, using bcp to export the data and then running the appropriate SQL commands in the database using osql, for example.

```
bcp {params} && osql {params}
```

Answer (score 1):

SSIS is definitely the best tool for this job. I'm curious as to why you think it is deprecated in SQL Server 2008, because as far as I know it's the best and most widely available option for ETL in the SQL Server ecosystem.

Comment: In fact I was thinking of "DTS", and could only find it under the Legacy tree. The fact that my instance didn't have Integration Services installed didn't help :)

Answer (score 0):

If SSIS is not an option, I would create a SQL Agent job, something like this

- Step 1. BCP flat files, on success goto step 2 else step 3
- Step 2. DELETE data from table, end
- Step 3. Error log

After that, you can schedule it run every night.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link:

http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s231/schedule_data_import_in_sql_server_pt1.htm

It does not tell you how to delete the data as you asked, but for anyone stumbling across this question in search of automated import or export of data from sql server to e.g. access, this link is an excellent start. It shows how to create an import/ export package, and more importantly, further posts also how to schedule it for routine excecution.